# Partition data from array and store in variable (Javascript / JSON)

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

I have a requirement where I need to partition incoming data to look like the following example:

```
//required payload

{
"campaign_id": "",
"recipient": {
    "first_name": "",
    "last_name": "",
    "company": "",
    "email": "",
    "address_1": "",
    "city": "",
    "state": "",
    "postal_code": "",
    "identifier": ""
    }
}
```

However, my issue is that the payload currently being posted to my endpoint looks like this:

```
//entire payload

"body": {
"info": [
{
"campaign_id": "",
"recipient": {
    "first_name": "",
    "last_name": "",
    "company": "",
    "email": "",
    "address_1": "",
    "city": "",
    "state": "",
    "postal_code": "",
    "identifier": ""
    }
}
],
"otherArray": [],
"otherString": "",
"otherString2": ""
}
}
```

What I want to do is extract the required data in my first example from the second example and then store it in a variable. Something like the below:

```
var requiredPayload = {"campaign_id": "", "recipient": {}};
```

What can I do to put `campaign_id` + `recipient` object in a single variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should be able to assign the first element of the info array to the *requiredPayload* variable, like so:

```js
 
   const payload = {
    "body": {
        "info": [
            {
                "campaign_id": "",
                "recipient": {
                    "first_name": "",
                    "last_name": "",
                    "company": "",
                    "email": "",
                    "address_1": "",
                    "city": "",
                    "state": "",
                    "postal_code": "",
                    "identifier": ""
                }
            }
        ],
        "otherArray": [],
        "otherString": "",
        "otherString2": ""
    }
};

var requiredPayload = payload.body.info[0];
console.log("requiredPayload:", requiredPayload);
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
    var data={"body": {
        "info": [
        {
        "campaign_id": "",
        "recipient": {
            "first_name": "",
            "last_name": "",
            "company": "",
            "email": "",
            "address_1": "",
            "city": "",
            "state": "",
            "postal_code": "",
            "identifier": ""
        }
        }
        ],
        "otherArray": [],
        "otherString": "",
        "otherString2": ""
        }
        };
    console.log(data.body.info[0]); //data is variable name
var info_data=data.body.info[0];
```

if info have multiple campaign_id then try this

```
$.each(data.body.info, function (indexInArray, valueOfElement) { 
    console.log(data.body.info[indexInArray]);
});
```